# Nginx upstream health check - custom header

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to setup Nginx plus to pass also `Host` header while execution a health check?

It looks like nginx resolves an IP address of the server and then using it instead of hostname specified. The issue is that the backed is not able to route requests without hostname provided.

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com:80 resolve fail_timeout=0 max_fails=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like every other use of `proxy_pass` nginx defaults to making an HTTP/1.0 connection to the upstream with the Host header set to the defined name of the `upstream` or its IP address.

You can set a Host header or HTTP/1.1 (or both) yourself to override these.

```
    location /health {
        health_check;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```